# Jenkins Job DSL gradle closure with parametrized switches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm trying to create a Jenkins job using JJ. DSL. I'm trying to create a comma separated string with the simulations I need to run. This is the job code:

```
job("run-simulations") {
  parameters {
    choiceParam('targetEnvironment', ['stage', 'dev'], 'Select the target environment')
    booleanParam('s1', true, 'include simulation 1')
    booleanParam('s2', true, 'include simulation 2')
    booleanParam('s3', true, 'include simulation 3')
    booleanParam('s4', true, 'include simulation 4')
  }
  steps {
    gradle {
      useWrapper true
      tasks 'clean runPerformanceTest'
      switches '''
          -DtargetEnvironment=\${targetEnvironment}
          -Dsimulations=${getSimulations(${s1}, ${s2}, ${s3}, ${s4})}
      '''
    }
  }
}

static def getSimulations(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
  String simulations = [
      s1 ? "Simulation1" : "",
      s2 ? "Simulation2" : "",
      s3 ? "Simulation3" : "",
      s4 ? "Simulation4" : ""
  ]
  
  return simulations.join(",")
}
```

I'm getting this result:

```
gradlew -DtargetEnvironment=dev -Dsimulations=${getSimulations(true, true, true, true)}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am using GString example as I do not have working Gradle on my computer:

```
pipeline{
    agent{label 'master'}
    stages{
        stage('1'){
            steps {
    script{
        def targetEnvironment="value1"
        def s1 = true
        def s2 = true
        def s3 = true
        def s4 = true
      String test1 = """
          -DtargetEnvironment=${targetEnvironment}
          -Dsimulations=${(getSimulations("$s1", "$s2", "$s3", "$s4"))}
      """
      echo test1
    }
    
  }
}
}
}

def getSimulations(s1, s2, s3, s4) {
  List<String> simulations = [
      s1 ? "Simulation1" : "",
      s2 ? "Simulation2" : "",
      s3 ? "Simulation3" : "",
      s4 ? "Simulation4" : ""
  ]
  
  return simulations.join(",")
}
```

You need to use round brackets for function invocation and pass parameters inside double quotes. Also you need to use `List<String>` type inside getSimulations function.

However, I would extract function from that place and pass variable with result only, for better clarity:

```
def targetEnvironment="value1"
        def s1 = true
        def s2 = true
        def s3 = true
        def s4 = true
        def simParams = getSimulations(s1, s2, s3, s4)
      String test1 = """
          -DtargetEnvironment=${targetEnvironment}
          -Dsimulations=${simParams}
      """
      echo test1
```